# Approximate solution for ODE

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to find approximate solution for nonlinear ODE(I know there are are ways to do it in mathematica) but I really want why is not working(I modified the code base on some codes suggest by expert here for system):

```
 ClearAll["Global`*"]
  eq = {u'[t] == u[t]^2 + 1, u[0] == 0} // Simplify


   u[t_] = Sum[ t^s, {s, 0, 6}] + O[t]^7;

   le = LogicalExpand[#] & /@ eq;

   sol1 = NSolve[And @@ le, Flatten[Table[s, {s, 0, 6}], 1]];

    uu1[t_] = Normal[{u[t]} /. First@sol1] // Simplify;

    uu1[t] // TableForm
     pl = Plot[Evaluate[{uu1[t]}, {t, 0, 6}], 
         PlotStyle -> {Blue}];
```

Comment: `NDSolve` is used to solve ODEs, not `NSolve`.  You might want to study some examples in its documentation, because I'm not sure how to fix your code.

Comment: Dear MichaelE2, the above code I modified it, it was suggested by  Akku14 for system, I am new here I do not know how to contact the expert directly....thanks

Comment: Maybe if you gave the mathematical formulation of the  problem -- but maybe Nasser has guessed correctly what you wanted in his answer, in which case I guess there's no further need for explanation.

Comment: Thank you Michael E2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the method i showed in other example, do it exactly the way. (Don't leave things or change arbitrarilly.)

```
    ClearAll["Global`*"]
eq = u'[t] == u[t]^2 + 1; ic = u[0] == 0;
u[t_] = Sum[a[s]*t^s, {s, 0, 6}] + O[t]^7
le = LogicalExpand[eq]
sol1 = Solve[le, Table[a[s], {s, 1, 6}]]
sol2 = Solve[ic /. sol1[[1]], a[0]]
uu1[t_] = u[t] /. First@sol1 /. First@sol2 // Normal // Simplify
pl = Plot[uu1[t], {t, 0, 6}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Blue}]
```

Comment: Dear Akku14, many thanks for the correct answer, can we do the same for  
      x y''(x)+2y'(x)+a x^(m+1) y(x)^n=0, y(0)=1, y'(0)=0

Comment: You can only do it, if you insert integer numbers for m and n. e.g. m -> 1, n -> 2.  Try it. Solve only for `y(0)=1 `  The `y'(0)=0 ` is satisfied with the given a.

Comment: So it can not done for any m, n, a? right?

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
ode = u'[t] - u[t]^2 - 1;
ic = u[0] == 0;
sol = u[t] /. First@DSolve[{ode == 0, ic}, u[t], t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Series[sol, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 AsymptoticDSolveValue[{ode == 0, ic}, u[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want to do the above yourself, then you would need to plug in Taylor series for $u(t)$ using rules given below on Wikpedia and this gives you a recursive relation to solve for the coefficients. the $c_0$ is found from initial conditions, which then leads to all the other coefficients being known due to recusive relation.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series_solution_of_differential_equations under the section **A simpler way using Taylor series** and follow the example given:

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you Naser, I highly appreciate your help.